# Onchange não dispara

Tags: javascript, select, toggle

Oie! Então, não to conseguindo adicionar um evento de **onchange** na minha select tag.

HTML

```
<select class="onchange">
  <option>Selecione um assunto:</option>
  <option value="pratica">Receita de pães caseiros</option>
  <option value="pao">Outras iniciativas Waldorf em Brasília</option>
  <option value="waldorf">Boas práticas para tempos de pandemia</option>
</select>
```

Eu quero que quando uma option for selecionada, a sessão com id idêntica apareça. Mas não to conseguindo nem adicionar o evento onchange. Já tentei vários códigos diferentes, mas nem aparece o console.

JS

```
//grab all ids
sectionTag.forEach(function(section){
  id = section.getAttribute("id")
  console.log(id)
})

const value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;

//grab values
select.addEventListener("onchange", function(event){
  console.log(value)
})
```

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Provavelmente é pq no **addEventListener()** não é **`onchange`**, mas, sim só **`change`**!

Comment: Simmmm! Agora funcionou ahsuahs Ai muito obrigada!! tava sofrendo aqui aushuash @LeAndrade

Comment: Blza Mari, o JavaScript é meio traiçoeiro quanto as nomenclaturas de vez em quando! Outra coisa ali vc nem precisa pegar o **event** basta declarar a propriedade `this` que será relacionada com o option do select assim: **console.log(this.value)**.

Answer (score 0):

Seu select tá errado, onchange não é uma classe e sim um evento, então o que precisa fazer é atribuir seu evento a ele.
Há varias maneiras de pegar os valores, uma bem simples seria essa:

```
<select id="assunto" onchange="getAssunto()">
  <option>Selecione um assunto:</option>
  <option value="pratica">Receita de pães caseiros</option>
  <option value="pao">Outras iniciativas Waldorf em Brasília</option>
  <option value="waldorf">Boas práticas para tempos de pandemia</option>
</select>
```

E no seu JS voce pega e usa da forma que quiser:

```
function getAssunto() {
    let assunto = document.getElementById('assunto').value;
    console.log(assunto);
  }
```

Vote positivo se te ajudou :)